# Null check operator used on a null value when use Get.offAll()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have this AuthController that extends GetxController. I have a worker that trigger a function when the firebase user state change:

```
  _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(_user, _initialScreen);
```

Then in _initialScreen I have this code:

```
 _initialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      Get.offAll(() =>  WelcomePage(email: user.email!));
    } else {
      Get.offAll(() => LoginPage());
    }
  }
```

The problem is that it gives me "Null check operator used on a null value" error, but if I use

> Get.to(LoginPage());

instead of

> Get.offAll(() => LoginPage());

the bug disappears. Can anyone explain why this happens, please?

EDIT: Just in case here is my main.dart:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) => Get.put(AuthController()));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(

      home: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        ScreenUtil.init(
            BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
            designSize: const Size(360, 690),
            context: context,
            minTextAdapt: true,
            orientation: Orientation.portrait);
        return SplashScreen();
      },)
    );}
}
```

EDIT 2: I'm posting AuthController.dart too:

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);

    //Si hay cambios nuestro usuario estará notificado
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(_user, _initialScreen);
  }

  _initialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      Get.offAll(() =>  WelcomePage(email: user.email!));

    } else {
      print('Welcome Page');
      Get.to(LoginPage());
    }
  }

  void register(String email, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password);
    } catch(e) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Algo ha fallado',
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        titleText: const Text(
          'El registro de usuario ha fallado',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black
          ),
        ),
        messageText: Text(
          e.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black
            )
        )
      );
    }
  }

  void login (String email, password) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } catch(e) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Algo ha fallado',
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          titleText: const Text(
            'La identificación ha fallado',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black
            ),
          ),
          messageText: Text(
              e.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black
              )
          )
      );
    }
  }

  void logOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

EDIT 3:
Providing StackTrace.

> Performing hot restart... Syncing files to device motorola one
> fusion... Restarted application in 1.476ms. I/flutter (32446): Auth en
> main User(displayName: , email: mail@mail.com, emailVerified: true,
> isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-03-02
> 20:10:35.002, lastSignInTime: 2022-03-04 06:27:24.770), phoneNumber: ,
> photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: , email:
> mail@mail.com, phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerId: password,
> uid: mail@mail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid:
> 9QUP1DFa3I5Odash56HmOG7f7ZGTEfdsxpFD2) [GETX] Instance
> "AuthController" has been created [GETX] Instance "AuthController" has
> been initialized [GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been
> created [GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
> I/flutter (32446): AuthController en onReady User(displayName: ,
> email: mail@mail.com, emailVerified: true, isAnonymous: false,
> metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-03-02 20:10:35.002,
> lastSignInTime: 2022-03-04 06:27:24.770), phoneNumber: , photoURL:
> null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: , email: mail@mail.com,
> phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid:
> mail@mail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid:
> 9QUP1DFIfsfdfe5O3h56HmOG7f7Z7GTE7pFD2) [GETX] GOING TO ROUTE
> /WelcomePage [GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /
>
> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following _CastError was thrown building WelcomePage(dirty): Null check operator used on a null value
>
> ## The relevant error-causing widget was:    WelcomePage
> WelcomePage:file:///Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/prjname/lib/core/services/auth_controller.dart:28:25
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Element.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3203:31)
> #1      StatelessElement.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4824:39)
> #2      debugCheckHasMediaQuery. (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:229:17)
> #3      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:245:4)
> #4      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:859:12)
> #5      ScreenUtil.screenHeight (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:74:36)
> #6      WelcomePage.build (package:paclage_/ui/views/welcome_page.dart:15:53)
> #7      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4827:28)
> #8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
> #9      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
> #10     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
> #11     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
> #12     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
> #13     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
> #14     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
> #15     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7) (elided 4 frames
> from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

Edit 4: The WelcomePage:file:///Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/prjname/lib/core/services/auth_controller.dart:28:25 line is this:

Get.offAll(() =>  WelcomePage(email: user.email!));

Comment: Could you check which line the "Null check operator used on a null value" error is thrown? The error usually occurs when a bang (!) operator is used on a nullable value that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace? And show the line of code where the exception occurs?

Comment: The problem has to do with the Get.ofAll and I know it because even I deleted the user parameter on WelcomePage the problem persists and the error shows each time I use Get.ofAll() no matter what screen I want to navigate and disappears when I use Get.to instead.

Comment: Multiple people trying to help you asked for a stack trace, yet you still haven't provided it.  Even if the stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown in the `Get.offAll` code, being able to see exactly what code is throwing the exception could help others determine what you did wrong to get into that bad state.

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry I've moved forward changing the flow, but you're right, so I've made some changes again and there is the stack trace just below the third edit.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently. I was using a `RouteHelper` class to manage the Routes in my app.

I created an `async` function  `Binding` the dependencies like `Controllers` and `Repositories` with `GetxControllers` and `GetService`. I called this function in the `main` function of my Flutter app.

I implemented `Get.offNamed()` while logging in and also while logging out. And after logging out if I tried to log in immediately without closing the app it gave the same error.

The error occurred due to a missing `Controller` that was supposed to be loaded before going to my `Landing Screen`.

So, I implemented:

```
Get.lazyPut(() => LandingScreenController());
```

in an appropriate place of my code again before `returning` or `building` the `widget` where an `instance` of my `LandingScreenController` is used. And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are Navigating to DashBoard from Login page.
Now use bellow code into your Dashboard page.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.lazyPut(()=>DashBoardController());
....
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, explain what it is doing, also images of code are not acceptable.